# how to send json array to different view controller in swift using segue

Tags: ios, json, swift

i want to send the json array from one view controller to another view controller and the array should be populated in pickerview . but i am unable to send the array . i am getting the array but not able to send it

```
let mydata = json["data"] as! NSArray    
                                print("My Data is \(mydata)")
                                var sendData = [NSArray]()
                                sendData = mydata as! Array<NSArray>
                                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "checkLoginViewController", sender: sendData)

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? SignupViewController, let sendData = sender as? [String]{    
                destinationVC.dept = sendData    
            }    
        }
```

secondVC:

```
var dept = [String]()
```

Comment: what error it displays ?

Comment: I have two questions : What is the purpose of adding **let sendData = sender as? [String]** in the condition AND is **destinationVC.dept = sendData** really called ?

Comment: the error is very big ... being new to swift i am learning as well how to properly debug and understand the error @NikunjDamani

Comment: i am using that because in stack-overflow i have found this solution soo i have tried that but its not working . so wanted to know if i am using the correct code or not and how i can achieve that  @Nitish

Comment: Tip: you should avoid using NSArray altogether. Stick to Swift arrays.

Comment: then should i convert the array to string and then send it ?? @Moritz

Comment: it will be helpful if you post the json

Comment: Try not to look for the solution but rather the issue. Then use your logics to fix that Check answer given by @Sh_Khan. The reason for error is the incorrect casting.

Comment: i am getting the json array in "mydata" . i am not able to send it through segue

Comment: yes . I will try that @Nitish

Comment: @AbhijitPatil I didn't talk about strings. I just said to not use NSArray and use a Swift array instead.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you use  `Array<NSArray>`

```
  endData = mydata as! Array<NSArray>
```

and in prepare cast it like

```
   let sendData = sender as? [String]
```

which for sure cast will fail

Comment: @AbhijitPatil : To add on this, you need to check the json response. That should be your starting point so as to which kind of data array you need to take.

Comment: can you use let mydata = json["data"]  print("\\(mydata)") , and attach it so we can guide you to the correct cast

Comment: My Data is ( IT , Accounts , HR ) @Sh_Khan

Comment: There you go. Take [String] in both cases.

Comment: IF IT,Accounts,HR are strings you can use **let mydata = json["data"] as! [String]**

Comment: but the data i am getting is in Array .. but i will do as you suggested .

Comment: No SIr . I dont hate it . i thought using NSarray is the best practice @Sh_Khan

Comment: Your code is in swift language , so it's better to make it swifty in everyThing as NSArray is objective-C related , there is no need to switch to swift if you still use OC syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? SignupViewController, let sendData = sender as? {    
            destinationVC.dept = sendData    
        }    
    }
```

try this code